# Relationship between O(n)- and SO(n)-representations?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Write $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ for the orthogonal and special orthogonal group of degree $n$ over the real numbers. Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are real, finite-dimensional and orthogonal $O(n)$-representations that are equivalent as $SO(n)$-representations. Is there a nice (computable) way of telling whether $V$ and $W$ are equivalent as $O(n)$-representations?

Comment: At least for odd $n$, I imagine it is sufficient to look at the action of $-I$.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the part "at least for odd $n$"?

Comment: For odd $n$, $-I$ has determinant $-1$. Since $-I$ is a (the only nontrivial) central element in $O(n)$, this gives a nice isomorphism between $O(n)$ and $SO(n)\times Z_2$. In the case of even $n$, the best you can do is that $O(n)$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product $SO(n)\rtimes G$, where $G=\{I,A\}$ for some orthogonal matrix $A$ for which $det(A)=-1$ and $A^2=I$.

Comment: But, even in the semidirect product case, all you need to do is check that $A$ acts "the same" on both representations. Basically, take the intertwining map that gives an isomorphism over $SO(n)$ and then see if this intertwines the action of $A$. If it does, then the representations are isomorphic. If it doesn't then you can't tell whether they are isomorphic or not but you can say that the original $SO(n)$ isomorphism is not an $O(n)$ isomorphism